# How do you use AWS User Pool functions in a Node.js Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to sign up a user using User Pools and have used and adapted the code from the example [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html) in my lambda.

I reference AWS in the normal manner:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

and attempt to reference an existing user pool:

```
AWS.config.region = 'eu-east-1';

var poolData = { 
    UserPoolId : 'eu-west-1_xxxxxxx',
    ClientId : 'xxxxxxx'
};

var userPool = AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
```

but I get the following error:

> TypeError: AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool is not a function

Am I using the wrong SDK? [the setup page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/setting-up-the-javascript-sdk.html) explains how aws-cognito-sdk.min.js is variant of the full SDK but references just the Cognito Identity Service, so I assume that the full SDK will also allow me to access it...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I've figured it out. Firstly, yes you can use the standard aws-sdk.
Here is the code:

```
var params = {
  ClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  Password: 'password',
  Username: 'Ross',
  UserAttributes: [
    {
      Name: 'email',
      Value: 'email@email.com'
    }
  ]
};
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.signUp(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
    context.fail(err);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
    context.succeed(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Perfect one shot answer. I was searching for one such simple example for more than 3 to 4 hours until I found this.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to perform Cognito requests using the pure SDK for JS just like you, but the examples I've seen use the cognito identity SDK. Could you tell me if you found any materials, and where, to get to your answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a syntax error in your code. Try changing this:

```
var userPool = newAWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
```

To this:

```
var userPool = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
```

Comment: thanks for spotting - that may have been whilst transferring to StackOverflow!