# AWS SDK - how to create a lambda function to listGroups from user pool?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm new at AWS Lambda Functions and I want to create a new function to fetch user groups from my Cognito User Pool generated by Amplify, I saw many examples but so far my function didn't work, I think I'm probably missing some permission, I'm not sure. Here is my function:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
    const params = { UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_xxxxxxx'};
    
    let res = { status: 'no changes' };
    
    cognito.listGroups(params, function(err, data) {
      console.log('inside of response')
      if (err) {
        res = { error: err };
      }
      else {
        res = { data: data };
      }
      
    })
    
    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(res),
    };
    return response; 
};
```

I already add permission following [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59045972/7390929)

I'm following [the API docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#listGroups-property) to call the Cognito `listGroups` method.

For permissions, the role associate with this function has this policy:
[image]

I'm doing everything online, and to test it I'm just using the Test button, so far the only response I got was: `{ status: 'no changes' }`, not even the log inside of the function is displayed.

How to make this function work to listGroups from my Amplify Cognito User Poll? Is there any permission missing?

Similar questions:

- [Listing users and their groups from
  AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.listUsers in a NodeJS Lambda
  function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59117691/listing-users-and-their-groups-from-aws-cognitoidentityserviceprovider-listusers)
- [Get Cognito user pool identity in Lambda
  function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574425/get-cognito-user-pool-identity-in-lambda-function)
- [How to access Cognito Userpool from inside a lambda
  function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62014773/how-to-access-cognito-userpool-from-inside-a-lambda-function)
- [How do you use AWS User Pool functions in a Node.js Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38683802/how-do-you-use-aws-user-pool-functions-in-a-node-js-lambda)

Comment: move cognito.listGroups to a separate function and return promise. Await  cognito.listGroups in handler for result

Comment: Thanks @Nonik. Moving the to separate function wasn't the answer but gave me an idea to use `.promise()` and get that function to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manager to get it to work:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
let cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();


exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const params = { UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_xxxxxxx'};
    
    let res = { status: 'no changes' };
    
    await cognito.listGroups(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res = { error: err };
      }
      else {
        res = { data: data };
      }
    }).promise();
    
    
    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(res),
    };
    return response; 
};
```

I was missing the `await` and the `.promise()` at the end of cognito call.